# Embed versioning number of my database as expected by my app

Tags: database, postgresql, versioning, h2

What ways might I use to identify the version of my database in Postgres?

On launch, I want my app to examine the database to verify if its structure is as expected. If the database is old and predates the app's expectations, I want to throw an exception. Likewise if the database is newer, having changes to its schema not expected by that codebase.

These needs are most likely to come up when restoring a backup of the database or when forking the app’s codebase.

Obviously one solution is to create an extra table with a single row with a single column name something like "structure_version_".

**Are there alternative places to tuck such meta-data?** In general? In Postgres specifically?

Comment: Having a table that stores the current version of the database model is a very common way of doing that. There is nothing wrong with it. If you use tools like Liquibase or Flyway they will manage that for you. You might want to look into them before rolling your own solution. Liquibase supports both Postgres and H2 and I'm sure Flyway does as well (but I only use Liquibase)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function much like `version()` to return the required information:

```
CREATE FUNCTION structure_version (OUT string text, OUT major int, OUT minor int) AS $$
BEGIN
  major := 4;
  minor := 1;
  string := 'My app is version ' || major || '.' || minor;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then:

```
SELECT * FROM structure_version;
```